# How to redirect in React Navigation after login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-native, react-navigation

StackNavigator is my configuration.

How do to redirect to another screen after user pressed login and successfully obtained a token. Below are the current screen.

```
const MainScreenNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Login: { screen: LoginScreen },
  Protected: { screen: ProtectedScreen },
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `navigate('Protected')`

and if you want to pass params `navigate('protected',{user:'John'})`

and retrive it as props `this.props.Navigation.state.params.user`

```
class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title : 'Login'
  };

  login() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    navigate('Protected', { user: 'John' })
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button
          onPress={() => this.login()}
          title="Login"
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```